# AngularJS show in div if date is today, otherwise show in other div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

The idea is that I have several items in my array, which have a title, company and date value. These are then shown in a div with ng-repeat.

What I want is for them to be shown in the first div if the date value is today's date and in a different div if the date value is not today. (Ideally, I would separate them in Today, Yesterday, Last Week, etc.)

What it currently does is show the dates in the first div and display their date as today, even though the value is not set like that in the array. And the second div is completely empty.

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("boardController", function($scope) {
    $scope.today= new Date();
    $scope.posts = [
       {
           "Title" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
           "Company" : "Microsoft",
           "Date" : "2016-06-19",

        },{
            "Title" : "Berglunds snabbköp",
            "Company" : "IBM",
            "Date" : "2016-06-18",
        },{
            "Title" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
            "Company" : "MexaTel",
            "Date" : "2016-06-03",
        },{
            "Title" : "Ernst Handel",
            "Company" : "BlaBlaCar",
            "Date" : "2016-06-11",
        }
    ]
});
```

The HTML is structured like this:

```
<body ng-controller="boardController">
        <!--  Products Container  -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <!--  Product Container  -->
            <h2>Today</h2>
            <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="post in posts">
                <div ng-if="post.Date = today">
                    <h3>
                        {{post.Title}}
                    </h3>
                    <h5>
                        {{post.Date | date : 'EEE MMM d'}}
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
            <h2>Yesterday</h2>
            <div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="post in posts">
                <div ng-if="post.Date > today">
                    <h3>
                        {{post.Title}}
                    </h3>
                    <h5>
                        {{post.Date | date : 'EEE MMM d'}}
                    </h5>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` and `===` are comparison operators.

Comment: @elclanrs with that changed, nothing shows up at all in the the first div OR the second div.

Comment: I believe `today` date can not be lesser than any other date in past.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Date` is a string and `today` is Date object you need to cast them both to the same type in order to compare properly. I would use [`date` filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) to format `today` to the same string as `Date`:

```
app.controller("boardController", function($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.today = $filter('date')(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
    // ...
});
```

and then in HTML you would have (note `===` comparison operator)

```
ng-if="post.Date === today"
```

Comment: Awesome! That works exactly like I had in mind. 

If you don't mind me asking, how would you go about making the second div display dates that are older than today, but not older than a week?

Comment: `post.Date > today` should work too with what I posted.

Comment: But how would you go about setting for example `$scope.yesterday`?

I'm trying `$scope.yesterday = $filter('date')(new Date().setDate($scope.today.getDate() - 1), 'yyyy-MM-dd');` but that doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You need to have a Date object in order to getDate. Check this demo I created about this: http://plnkr.co/edit/9vJjYUTuIKZmvGjgnqRf?p=preview

Comment: That's awesome. Thank you so much.